# SQL Group by date and show each category from one day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tabled named `categories` and a table named `posts`. Each post has date, title, id and catID. How can I make a query that returns the first post of each cateogry ordered by date.

Example:

```
Post_ID 1 "Title 1"  "Cat1" "26-03.2013 13:00"
Post_ID 2 "Title 2"  "Cat1" "26-03.2013 13:05"
Post_ID 3 "Title 3"  "Cat1" "25-03.2013 13:00"
Post_ID 4 "Title 4"  "Cat1" "25-03.2013 13:05"


Post_ID 5 "Title 5"  "Cat2" "26-03.2013 14:00"
Post_ID 6 "Title 6"  "Cat2" "26-03.2013 14:05"
Post_ID 7 "Title 7"  "Cat2" "25-03.2013 14:00"
Post_ID 8 "Title 8"  "Cat2" "25-03.2013 14:05"

Post_ID 9 "Title 9"  "Cat3" "26-03.2013 15:00"
Post_ID 10 "Title 10"  "Cat3" "26-03.2013 15:05"
Post_ID 11 "Title 11"  "Cat3" "25-03.2013 15:00"
Post_ID 12 "Title 12"  "Cat3" "25-03.2013 15:05"
```

The result would be:

```
26-03-2013
Post ID10 (15:05) CAT 3
POST ID8  (14:05) CAT 2
POST ID4  (13:05) CAT 1


25-03-2013
Post ID12 (15:05) CAT 3
POST ID6  (14:05) CAT 2
POST ID2  (13:05) CAT 1
```

Comment: This question is asked a hundred times a day on SO - as well as on dedicated MySQL forums. Oh, and it's covered in the manual too.

Comment: @Strawberry Can you please give me a link? I always search for a solution before asking a question, but this time i really couldn't find one.

Comment: Look for groupwise max. There are various solutions but uncorrelated sub-queries are usually fastest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query,

```
$query ='SELECT categories.*, posts.* FROM categories, posts WHERE categories.id = posts.catID GROUP BY posts.catID ORDER BY posts.date DESC';
```

Read about JOIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Read about GROUP BY: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Read about ORDER BY: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

may this help you.

Comment: They are returned grouped by category but they aren't fragmented on dates. So the posts from one category are displayed only in the first day and not in the following posts.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(posts.feedID) FROM feeds, posts WHERE feeds.ID = posts.feedID ORDER BY ' at line 1

feeds = categories
posts = posts
feedID = catID

And here is the exact query that i have input 
SELECT feeds.*, posts.*, DISTINCT(posts.feedID) FROM feeds, posts WHERE feeds.ID = posts.feedID ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC

Comment: @TudorRavoiu check & let you know.

Comment: Thank you anyway for the help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26925/discussion-between-advait-amin-and-tudor-ravoiu)